# Matlab / Octave number sequence

Tags: matlab, octave, sequences

I know I can create a number sequence in octave / matlab using **1:1:5** will give me **1,2,3,4,5**

But how can I get a sequence of `1/5, 1/4, 1/3, 1/2, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5`

Thanks
I'm using octave 3.8.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you need?

```
n = 5;
sequence = [ 1./(n:-1:1) 1:n ];
```